# Django 1.5 with psycopg2 throw random errors

Tags: python, django, psycopg2, gunicorn

I faced with some strange problem. When I run single worker for my django application? like this:

```
python manage.py run_gunicorn -w 1
python manage.py runserver
```

All requests served correctly, but if start multiple workers like:

```
python manage.py run_gunicorn -w 10
```

Django respond with error to (about) half of my requests:

```
2013-06-13 18:02:39 [10205] [ERROR] Error handling request
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/mezhenin/venv/karma/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/sync.py", line 130, in handle_request
    for item in respiter:
  File "/home/mezhenin/venv/karma/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/raven/middleware.py", line 27, in __call__
    iterable = self.application(environ, start_response)
  File "/home/mezhenin/venv/karma/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 255, in __call__
    response = self.get_response(request)
  File "/home/mezhenin/venv/karma/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 177, in get_response
    signals.got_request_exception.send(sender=self.__class__, request=request)
  File "/home/mezhenin/venv/karma/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/dispatch/dispatcher.py", line 170, in send
    response = receiver(signal=self, sender=sender, **named)
  File "/home/mezhenin/venv/karma/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/__init__.py", line 68, in _rollback_on_exception
    transaction.rollback_unless_managed(using=conn)
  File "/home/mezhenin/venv/karma/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/transaction.py", line 143, in rollback_unless_managed
    connection.rollback_unless_managed()
  File "/home/mezhenin/venv/karma/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/__init__.py", line 232, in rollback_unless_managed
    self._rollback()
  File "/home/mezhenin/venv/karma/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/__init__.py", line 59, in _rollback
    return self.connection.rollback()
OperationalError: no connection to the server
```

I tried sqlite3 as DB backend for Django and it works fine. Do someone have the same problems with psycopg2?

```
Django==1.5
gunicorn==0.17.2
psycopg2==2.5
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for disturbing. Problem was not in psycopg/Django/gunicorn. I use Nose for testing purposes:

```
==== settings.py ====
INSTALLED_APPS = INSTALLED_APPS + ('django_nose',)
TEST_RUNNER = 'django_nose.NoseTestSuiteRunner'
NOSE_ARGS = ['--with-doctest']
```

when removed this lines, random errors disappear.